# SQL Query to fetch data in single transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table to keep friend information, with columns `MemberID` and `FriendID`. Here is some sample data:

```
RecordID MemberID FriendID
-------- -------- --------
   1        10       12    
   2        12       10    
   3        10       14    
   4        15       10    
   5        14       12    
   6        10       13    
   7        11       13
```

I need to find the friends of any Member, either in the `MemberID` column or the `FriendID` column.

For example:

- The friends for `MemberID` 10 are 12, 13, 14, 15.
- The friends for `MemberID` 14 are 10, 12.

I have tried many ways to get the values with a query, but all in vain.

Please suggest the best SQL query to accomplish the task in a single statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take one scan. There is no need to do a `UNION`--which will require 2 scans and be worse performance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   M.FriendID
FROM
   dbo.Friend F
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (F.MemberID, F.FriendID),
      (F.FriendID, F.MemberID)
   ) M
WHERE
   M.MemberID = 10;
```

[See this working in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8fb9/2).

Now to contradict myself--I thought about this a little more. My statement about the scans is only true if you don't have indexes. But, if you have a separate index on both `MemberID` and `FriendID` (either one clustered, and the other one nonclustered), then a `UNION` method will in fact perform better, because it will do two seeks instead of a scan. So because of this, I actually recommend that you stick with `UNION` and get those indexes going.

```
SELECT FriendID FROM dbo.Friend WHERE MemberID = 10
UNION
SELECT MemberID FROM dbo.Friend WHERE FriendID = 10;
```

Furthermore, I recommend that no matter which query you choose, that you remove the `RecordID` column from your `Friend` table. This column is totally unnecessary, as any time you want to refer to a relationship between friends you can simply use the composite key of `(MemberID, FriendID)`. By removing this column, each row will take fewer bytes, which will gain more rows per page, which will result in fewer reads to get the same data--a performance-improving win. If you have no other columns in the table, you will get 50% more rows per page by removing `RecordID`!

Here's how you could implement these recommendations:

```
-- if RecordID is part of the PK
ALTER TABLE dbo.Friend DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Whatever;

-- if RecordID is part of a separate non-PK clustered index
DROP INDEX dbo.Friend.CI_Whatever;

-- If the PK is not already over these two columns
ALTER TABLE dbo.Friend
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Friend PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MemberID, FriendID);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Friend_FriendID_MemberID
   ON dbo.Friend (FriendID) -- MemberID is implicitly included.
```

Note that the final nonclustered index is now a "covering" index for the second part of the `UNION` query above, meaning it won't need to hit the clustered index to satisfy that portion of the query. So you now get 2 seeks and performance is best.

Comment: An interesting note: through this query, totally by accident I learned that SQL Server will infer column names from *a VALUES clause* (not just a SELECT clause). WHOA! I had no clue it could do that. Amazing!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a query with a union?

```
SELECT FriendID
FROM mytable
WHERE MemberID = {The ID}
UNION
SELECT MemberID AS FriendID
FROM mytable
WHERE FriendID = {The ID}
```

If you need it to be distinct and there may be overlaps, you can also use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FriendID
FROM (
    SELECT FriendID
    FROM mytable
    WHERE MemberID = {The ID}
    UNION
    SELECT MemberID AS FriendID
    FROM mytable
    WHERE FriendID = {The ID}
) Derived
```

And just to be very clear, be sure to replace `{The ID}` with whatever ID you are looking for.